# C - Using typedefs in methods

Tags: c

i'm trying to make a basic game which uses a structure for the player / enemy information

```
typedef struct Entities {
char Name[100];
int Health;
int Strength;
int Defence;
} Entity;
```

I have a method in which the user creates their character

```
void CreateCharacter() {
system("cls");
printf("Please enter your name: ");
fgets(Player.Name, strlen(Player.Name), stdin);
Player.Name[strlen(Player.Name) - 1] = '\0';
printf("%s's Stats\n",Player.Name);
Player.Health = 10;
Player.Strength = 10;
Player.Defence = 10;
printf("Health - %d\n", Player.Health);
printf("Strength - %d\n", Player.Strength);
printf("Defence - %d\n", Player.Defence);
printf("Is this okay?");
getch();
}
```

And the Entity "Player" is defined outside of the main method or other functions. The issue is that the Player Entity's name cannot be inputted. It skips the fgets part completely. What am I doin wrong?

Comment: fgets should have the buffer size as parameter, not the string length of the uninitialized string (which may be garbage).

Comment: I see but if in the typedef it is stated that it is 100 C long, why does it not work?

Comment: Because fgets wants to know how many characters it is allowed to read and the programmer must tell it the maximum. It can't see the typedef.

Comment: use `sizeof` here.

Comment: Also, `Name[strlen(Name)-1] = '\0'` does not do anything useful, because `strlen(Name)` looks for the first `'\0'` character in `Name`.

Comment: C doesn't have "methods".

Comment: fgets(Player.Name, 100, stdin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strlen(Player.Name)
```

returns 0, because of uninitialized string. That means you want to get 0 characters from stdin in fgets(). You must specify buffer size (max wanted value of input name string).

Comment: Lundin was first i can see :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it *isn't* uninitialized. It is *default-initialized*

Comment: *"returns 0"* - If you are lucky :\

Comment: @StorytiTeller in this case, it was default-initialized as described in the question :P

Comment: Sure, my bad. Too much Java oriented.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - My excuse for not catching that is that it was described in a natural language, and not a programming one